# Hide Google Maps API until requested

Tags: javascript, css, popupwindow

I won't add any code as this should be fairly straight forward. 
If I want to load the Google Maps API and embed it within my page, but I want to hide the viability of it until a user clicks a button, or a link, how do I go about doing that?

I'm not talking about markers and icons within the API, I want to hide the element itself that google maps uses, I think it's an iframe?

Ideally I want the user to click a "directions" button, which opens the google maps API as a popup within the same page. Allowing the user to close the popup if needed and return to where they were on the page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
TIA

Comment: Assuming Google Maps instructs you to add specific HTML to your page which it binds the map to, why not just initialize that HTML with CSS of "display: none", and then when the user clicks your button, change the CSS of that element to "display: block"?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `<script>` tag they give you, it looks something like this:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`

Just take out the `&callback=initMap` part. Then, when the user clicks to open the popup, call `initMap()` from your code.

jQuery: `$('#mapPopup').click(initMap);`